# Exp lambda dot notation?

Tags: notation

In a machine learning paper I'm reading, I came across the following notation:

> In our experiments we parameterize these potential functions as
>   an exponential of a linear scoring function
>
> $\Phi(a_{i-1},a_i,\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}) = \operatorname{exp}\Lambda\cdot\mathbf{f}(a_{i-1},a_i,\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})$
>
> where $\mathbf{f}$ is a vector of *feature
>   functions*...

What does the "$\operatorname{exp}\Lambda\cdot$" notation mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dot product of vectors.  If $\Lambda = (\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dots,\lambda_n)$ and the components of $\mathbf f$ are $f_1,f_2,\dots, f_n$, then the dot product is
$$
\Lambda\cdot\mathbf{f}(a_{i-1},a_i,\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})
=
\lambda_1 f_1(a_{i-1},a_i,\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})+
\lambda_1 f_1(a_{i-1},a_i,\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})+\dots+
\lambda_n f_n(a_{i-1},a_i,\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})
$$
which is what they called a "linear scoring function".  So $\mathbf f$ is a "vector of feature functions", and $f_1, f_2, \dots, f_n$ are the "feature functions".  I used $n$ for the number of features.

Then you take the exponential of that.